# Using the pumping lemma to prove irregularity in a regular language - where is the error

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

I have a vital misunderstanding of the pumping lemma. In the following example I show an example of using it on a regular language to come to incorrect conclusions. What am I doing wrong?

`L={a*b*},` assume the language is regular so by the pumping lemma there exists some n, and `σ = αβγ` and `σ' = αβ^kγ ∈ L` for all non negative k.

```
σ = aaabbb

α = aa

β = ab

γ = bb
```

then `σ'= αβ^2γ for k=2, σ' =aaababbb`

`σ'∉ L, a` contradiction, thus L is not regular.

L as described I know to be a regular language so I would expect to find ∈ L. This is due to my choice of β spanning across two characters but there is nothing I can find in the pumping lemma which forbids this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is it not (yet) a computer programming question. It's a question about the theory of regular languages.

Comment: my mistake. I asked the question again here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110527/using-pumping-lemma-to-prove-irregulairt-of-regular-language-what-is-my-error